# Files downloaded from TOR could have trackers which act through outgoing connections. How to identify and remove the trackers?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firewall, malware

Sorry, I'm new to this. From TOR's FAQ: Don't open documents downloaded through Tor while online

> Tor Browser will warn you before automatically opening documents that
> are handled by external applications. DO NOT IGNORE THIS WARNING. You
> should be very careful when downloading documents via Tor (especially
> DOC and PDF files, unless you use the PDF viewer that's built into Tor
> Browser) as these documents can contain Internet resources that will
> be downloaded outside of Tor by the application that opens them. This
> will reveal your non-Tor IP address. If you must work with files
> downloaded via Tor, we strongly recommend either using a disconnected
> computer, or using dangerzone to create safe PDF files that you can
> open. Under no circumstances is it safe to use BitTorrent and Tor
> together, however.

I assume that files like images and videos could also be bugged with trackers. The FAQ suggests method to contain the files but I'd like to know if they can be sanitized instead.
Can the trackers be identified with antiviruses like Malwarebytes? Can they be deleted if I convert the file through softwares like Photoshop or HandBrake?

Comment: Just be aware of kinds of files that can embed scripts, such as .wmv, .wma, .mp4 etc. Always use secure alternatives for opening these files, it would be better to open a .mp4 file in SMPlayer rather than in the Windows Media Player.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your file to a pure text file, that should be almost save from aspect of online tracing by viewing your file, if you are connected to the internet . All other formats are known as potential more critical.

If you open your downloaded files, only if you are offline (switch of your internet connection), that should be save in some aspects of online tracing, also.